Splitting SQL Server Database
I'm new to SQL Servers, as Access has always been appropriate for my previous dbs.
I've created 4 large dbs, in MSSMS, but they each have some 'list' tables that are duplicated across all 4.  For example, each db have 2 tables; Countries and units of measurement.
In Access, I would create a 'Universal Tables' db and link the 4 primary dbs to this.  Is this something I could do in an SQL server, or are there different protocols?  There are many more similar dbs in the pipeline, so I wanted to get it right first time.
Thanks in advance.

Create a separate database with these shared tables. Use complete table name as database.schema.table in your queries and/or create according synonims.

Thank you, that's the confirmation that I'm on the right track I needed.
